# How to setup Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher to run automatically using parameters during installation?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have to create setup.ini file for MS Sql server 2017 that sets it up in a certain way. At the moment I need to make Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher automatic, but there is nothing about it in Microsoft docs. The whole thing works in a way that the user starts a bat file that feeds the installation exec with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is using a command after installation:

```
Set-Service -name 'MSSQLFDLauncher$DATABASENAME' -StartupType Automatic
```